# jQuery take specific div's text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu where  I'd like to retrieve the text within the div so I tried writing something like this

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
  var linkValue = $(".link").text();
  alert(linkValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div class="link"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
  <div class="link"><a href="#">Apartment</a></div>
  <div class="link"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
  <div class="link"><a href="#">About us</a></div>
</div>
```

But it takes all the values of each class. Is it possible to make it take only the div's text I clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **this** inside the click function:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
        var linkValue = $(this).text();
        alert(linkValue);
    });
```